# office add-ins / Excel add-in - Can I run SQL Query in Excel add-in

Tags: sql, excel, office-addins, excel-addins

I am working on an excel add-in. I want to know if there is a way to fetch answer from the table in the excel sheet using an SQL query.

For example:

I have a table as below in the excel sheet:

**Height**   **Width**

**10**       **5**

**20**     **10**

my SQL query is: select height from table where width = 5

So is there a way where I can run this query and it will give me the answer.

If not, then is there a way by which I can create a database from excel and run this query and fetch the result.

Comment: You should usé ADODB like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385245/using-excel-vba-to-run-sql-query)

Comment: @DonKnacki I want to connect to the database using the excel add-in taskpane (React). Can I use ADODB in taskpane? sorry i am new to excel add-in.